# what does "internal-only" means in mount command and why wouldn't you call the /sbin/mount filesystem?

Tags: bash, mount, chrome-os

the followed  command, it's used to make executables at the user's home directory

```bsh
mount -i -o remount,exec /home/chronos/user
```

- I know that `-o` argument is for options, in this case **remount** and make **executables** at user home directory.

##### From the manual of mount:

> -i, --internal-only
> Don't call the /sbin/mount.filesystem helper even if it exists.

Why wouldn't you call the sbin/mount filesystem?

##### examples please.

Answer (score 5):

Some filesystem (usually those implemented with [FUSE](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fuse.html)) have special mount programs in `/sbin`, for example the NTFS FUSE driver ntfs-3g has its own `mount.ntfs-3g`. If you don't use the `-i` option this program will be called by the `mount` command instead of calling the [mount syscall](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) when mounting the filesystem.

So for NTFS you can do something like

```
$ sudo mount /dev/vdb2 /mnt/test -i
```

to force the kernel NTFS driver

```
$ mount | grep vdb2
/dev/vdb2 on /mnt/test type ntfs (ro,relatime,uid=0,gid=0,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1
```

see the type here is `ntfs` and the filesystem is mounted read-only (`ro`) because the kernel driver doesn't support read-write.

Compared to the default without `-i` which will use `mount.ntfs-3g` which uses the FUSE driver

```
$ sudo mount /dev/vdb2 /mnt/test
$ mount | grep vdb2
/dev/vdb2 on /mnt/test type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

the type is now `fuseblk` (because NTFS-3G is a FUSE driver) and the filesystem is mounted as read-write.

You can also use the `LIBMOUNT_DEBUG=all` environmental variable to get debug output for `mount`.

Without `-i` it calls the `/sbin/mount.ntfs` helper:

```
2124: libmount:      CXT: [0x5584880d2a50]: mount: do mount
2124: libmount:      CXT: [0x5584880d2a50]: mount: executing helper /sbin/mount.ntfs
2124: libmount:      CXT: [0x5584880d2a50]: mount: generate helper mount options
2125: libmount:      CXT: [0x5584880d2a50]: argv[0] = "/sbin/mount.ntfs"
2125: libmount:      CXT: [0x5584880d2a50]: argv[1] = "/dev/vdb2"
2125: libmount:      CXT: [0x5584880d2a50]: argv[2] = "/mnt/test"
2125: libmount:      CXT: [0x5584880d2a50]: argv[3] = "-o"
2125: libmount:      CXT: [0x5584880d2a50]: argv[4] = "rw"
2124: libmount:      CXT: [0x5584880d2a50]: /sbin/mount.ntfs executed [status=0, rc=0]
```

With `-i` it just calls the mount syscall:

```
2119: libmount:      CXT: [0x559aa1a8ba50]: mount: do mount
2119: libmount:      CXT: [0x559aa1a8ba50]: mount(2) [source=/dev/vdb2, target=/mnt/test, type=ntfs,  mountflags=0x00000000, mountdata=<none>]
```